# How can I stop line from extending for example: I am using auto trendlines and I want them to stop extending where the 2 lines cross

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I used line.new() to create a line but I do I stop it from extending with conditions?

I’ve tried looking it up on YouTube, Pinescirpt-v5 manual, etc…

Answer (score 0):

You extend it manually until you don't want to do it anymore. So configure your lines as `extend=extend.none` and then use `line.set_x2()` to update `x2` of your lines.

For example:

```
if (not lines_crossed)  // Two lines have not been crossed yet
    line.set_x2(line_1, bar_index)
    line.set_x2(line_2, bar_index)
```